# Does the "Tea" card apply to a multiple set of cards from a single player?

Tags: sushi-go-party

If Chris has a "Tea" card and his largest set are 2 "Temaki," 2 "Edamame," and 2 "Pudding" cards, does he only score 2 points for the "Tea," or 6 points?

Answer (score 3):

The Tea card can only count the cards in your single largest set of cards with the same background colour.

When you have multiple possible largest sets due to a tie, you can still only use it against the cards from a single set, so you have to pick one of them. So the Tea card is only worth 2 points in your example.

The [rulebook](http://www.gamewright.com/gamewright/pdfs/Rules/SushiGoPartyTM-RULES.pdf) (page 15) states:

> **TEA**
>
> **End of the round:** Count the number of cards in your largest (or tied
> for largest) set of cards with the same background color. Tea is worth
> 1 point per card in that set.